# Can an IOS app be tracked from download to install?

Tags: iphone, ios

A lot of websites have links to apps that will take you to the app's page on the Apple App Store. I am a web programmer and I understand how to track which sites are being used most often and which ones are getting the most clicks. I was wondering however if there is a way to track if the app was installed? I am guessing this would only be possible if you could pass user-defined variables to the app store with some sort of identifier for the particular website the link we clicked from. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Store does not, by itself, provide a way of accessing this information.

There may be a few other options, such as setting up the installed app to send a message to the server when it's first run, but as for a direct callback for a user tapping the "Install" button, there is none.

Comment: I did not think there was a way but wanted to check with the community. Thanks for replying.

Comment: "such as setting up the installed app to send a message to the server when it's first run" However, there would be no way to match this with where the user came from to install the app.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know how many user have downloaded your app you can integrate third party library Flurry.for more info just go through this link  [flurry](http://www.flurry.com/)

Comment: That is helpful information although that isn't quite what I was looking for.

Comment: @pogeybait what do you exactly  want ?

Comment: What Im looking for is simple. Let's say I have two websites, siteA and siteB. Both sites have a link to my app's Apple Store page. I setup a tracking link, something like http://mydomain.com/track?id=siteA to track which sites are being used most often and the link forwards the user onto the app's Apple store page. But here is where I want to go a step further. I want to know if a user installed the app and if so did they come from siteA or siteB. This is the part that I know is impossible.